# Create a table from an array of one-to-one correspondance

Tags: multidimensional-array

Edit: the number of possible object is unknown for each subject, and the total number of object is also unknown, so a simple for loop on each subject or each object cannot do it. I stuck here. Basically, I stuck on converting this input 2D array into the 2D array of table.

For example:

Input:

```
1 AA
1 ABC
2 AA
2 DAB
2 DOCI
3 DAB
4 ABC
4 CP
```

Output:

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | O | O |  |  |
| ABC | O |  |  | O |
| CP |  |  |  | O |
| DAB |  | O | O |  |
| DOCI |  | O |  |  |

Comment: What are we looking at here? Output as HTML? At the absolute least this should be something sketched in as Perl if it's a Perl question.

Comment: Any table format is OK, for simplicity, let say CSV,

Comment: Well, sure, but you're going to have to try something first.

Comment: I stuck after creating the 2D array input. Well, the number of object is unknown for each subject, and the total number of object is also unknown, so a simple loop cannot do it.

Comment: Well, you could at least show us that code.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use Data::Dumper;
use 5.01800;
use warnings;

my $_href;
while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    my ($numeric,$alphabetic)=split(/ /);
    $_href->{$alphabetic}[$numeric]++;
    };
# Let's see what we have
warn Data::Dumper->new([\$_href],[qw(*_href)])->Deepcopy(1)->Indent(1)->Purity(1)->Sortkeys(1)->Dump();

for my $key (sort keys %{$_href}) {
    # print label
    printf "%8s",$key;
    # print values
    for my $index (@{$_href->{$key}}) {
        print defined $index ? ' x ' : '   ';
        };
    print "\n";
    };

__DATA__
1 AA
1 ABC
2 AA
2 DAB
2 DOCI
3 DAB
4 ABC
```

which yields

```
    $_href = \{
    'AA' => [
      undef,
      1,
      1
    ],
    'ABC' => [
      undef,
      1,
      undef,
      undef,
      1
    ],
    'CP' => [
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      undef,
      1
    ],
    'DAB' => [
      undef,
      undef,
      1,
      1
    ],
    'DOCI' => [
      undef,
      undef,
      1
    ]
  };
      AA    x  x
     ABC    x        x
      CP             x
     DAB       x  x
    DOCI       x
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the method. I didn't realize "hash" is the key to solve the problem, and didn't realize array can initialize at random index with the rest still "undef".